# Verify eager loading programmatically in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a large query that joins a lot of mapped classes, and it uses a few `contains_eager` and `joinedload` options. I would like to write a unit test to verify that all relations for a target instance have in fact been eagerly loaded. Is there a way to ask an object instance whether a specific relationship has been eagerly loaded, or if it will be lazily fetched from the database upon attribute access? I know I can verify it manually by turning on SQL query logging and watching the log while accessing the relationships.

Comment: I am pretty sure that is possible to check loading state of each element of an instance : i would start reading this documentation : http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_state_management.html